# Why i cant stop the program using break?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

```
    choice = ''
    
    import pandas as pd
    
    def recordData():
        dataSensor = int(input("\nChoose Data Sensor [1/2] : "))
        if dataSensor == 1:
            count = 0
            filedata1 = open("dataSensor1.txt", "w")
            filedata1.write("SensorID,City,PressureReading\n")
            file = filedata1
            num = int(input("How many inputs that will be entered ? :"))
            while count < num:
                sensorId = input("\nEnter the Sensor ID : ")
                cityName = str(input("Enter the name of the city : "))
                pressure = input("Enter the pressure reading : ")
                count += 1
                file.write(sensorId + "," + cityName + "," + pressure + "\n")
            file.close()
        else:
            count = 0
            filedata2 = open("dataSensor2.txt", "w")
            filedata2.write("SensorID,City,PressureReading\n")
            file = filedata2
            num = int(input("How many inputs that will be entered ? :"))
            while count < num:
                sensorId = input("\nEnter the Sensor ID : ")
                cityName = str(input("Enter the name of the city : "))
                pressure = input("Enter the pressure reading : ")
                count += 1
                file.write(sensorId + "," + cityName + "," + pressure + "\n")
            file.close()
        main()
    
    def fileImport():
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        return df
    
    
    def ConcatenateDF():
        dataFrame1 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor1.txt", sep=",")
        dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor2.txt", sep=",")
        df = pd.concat([dataFrame1,dataFrame2], ignore_index = True)
        return df
    
    def highLowReading():
        print("\nHighest Pressure Reading")
        dataFrame1 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor1.txt", sep=",")
        dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor2.txt", sep=",")
        df = pd.concat([dataFrame1, dataFrame2], ignore_index=True)
        maxP = df["PressureReading"]
        high = maxP.max()
        maxRead = df[df["PressureReading"] == high]
        print(maxRead.sum())
        print("\nLowest Pressure Reading")
        minP = df["PressureReading"]
        low = minP.min()
        minRead =  df[df["PressureReading"] == low]
        print(minRead.sum())
    
    def avgReading():
        dataFrame1 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor1.txt" , sep=',')
        dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor2.txt", sep=',')
        dataFrame3 = pd.concat([dataFrame1, dataFrame2], ignore_index=True)
        total = dataFrame3["PressureReading"].sum()
        count = dataFrame3["PressureReading"].count()
        avgRead = total / count
        print("Average pressure reading : %.3f psi"%(avgRead))

 def main():
        while True :
            print("\n\t\t\t-----CHOICES-----")
            print("\n[A] Enter sensors pressure data and keep in files.")
            print("[B] Import & Display data sensor 1.")
            print("[C] Import & Display data sensor 2.")
            print("[D] Combine & Display two data frame.")
            print("[E] Find & Display highest and lowest pressure reading.")
            print("[F] Calculate & Display the average pressure reading.")
            print("[G] Stop the program.")
    
            choice = str.upper(input("\nEnter you choice [A/B/C/D/E/F/G] : "))
            if choice == 'A':
                recordData()
            elif choice == 'B':
                dataFrame1 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor1.txt", sep=",")
                print(dataFrame1)
            elif choice == 'C':
                dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv("dataSensor2.txt", sep=",")
                print(dataFrame2)
            elif choice == 'D':
                df = ConcatenateDF()
                print(df)
            elif choice == 'E':
                highLowReading()
            elif choice == 'F':
                avgReading()
            elif choice == 'G':
                print("You have decided to stop the program.")
            else:
                print("Entered choice invalid ! Please enter new choice.")
                break

    main()
```

Comment: Don't you want your `break` under choice `'G'`?

Comment: yes, i wanted the program to end when i enter 'G' but it wont stop

Comment: Of course it won't stop because you don't call `break` if the choice is `'G'`.

Comment: So why did you put the `break` where it's dealing with an invalid choice instead of with the `'G'` choice?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is exit() which closes the python program entirely and what break does is breaking a for or while loop. hope this helped

Comment: Using `exit` is the wrong approach. From the documentation of [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) (and `quit`): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

is your main() indented properly?

In the example your calling main() in the main function.

As once I corrected it your code works fine.

[image]

Comment: may i know how you corrected it

Answer (score 0):

First, You did not write the problem understandable.
Second, If you want "break" to work, you should use it under all conditions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).